# GPS in gazebo simulation

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

I got a robot model with an IMU that works and I want to fuse that with the ros package robot_localization. Now I want to add GPS data to fuse it with the IMU data. But I can't get it  to work. Currently I get this error:

_Sensor[gps] is attempting to load a plugin, but detected an incorrect plugin type. Plugin filename[libhector_gazebo_ros_gps.so] name[name_gps]

This is the code, the format is sdf and based on the tutorial:

> 1  
>     10.0  
>     base_footprint  
>     fix  
>     fix_velocity  
>     5.0 5.0 5.0  
>     0.1 0.1 0.1  
>     0 0 0  
>     0.1 0.1 0.1

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8883/gps-in-gazebo-simulation/) by [TJAN](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1231/tjan/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-06-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

According to the [source code](https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_gazebo/blob/indigo-devel/hector_gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_gps.cpp#L241) the hector gps plugin is a model plugin. This means the SDF plugin specification should be a child of `<model>`. Your code snippet has the plugin a child of `<sensor>`.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2015-06-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TJAN](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1231/tjan/) on 2015-06-10**:
Thanks, it worked!